# Openbravo installation under CentOS

Tags: centos, openbravo

I have a question according openbravo installation:
it can't start hunging up on:

```
[main] DEBUG org.openbravo.dal.core.OBTuplizer - Created tuplizer for org.openbravo.model.financialmgmt.cashmgmt.CashJournal
```

in opebravo.log message and sometimes followed by :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
```

Exception in catalina.out (but sometimes not)

The only error message during ant install.source compilation was:

```
 "Error executing moduleScript: 

        org.openbravo.modulescript.AdminFlagOnCreateDefaults ", but nevertheless build reported as successfull, openbravo has been deployed but not starting well.
```

I have tried to change CATALINA_OPTS to `-server -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms384M -Xmx1536M -XX:MaxPermSize=768M`, but with no effect. Openbravo hangs on `Created tuplizer for ...CashJournal` without OutOfMemory Exception.

CATALINA_BASE,CATALINA_HOME, JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME was configured properly.

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
Server built:   Apr 29 2013 11:34:47
Server number:  6.0.0.37
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.i686
Architecture:   i386
JVM Version:    1.7.0_45-b18
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

What am I doing wrong? 
I have Apach webserver configured, which proxies 8080 port. Should I run "ant smartbuild" additionally?
How to avoid "Error executing moduleScript: org.openbravo.modulescript.AdminFlagOnCreateDefaults " error during compillation?
How to make openbravo start?

PS: I have tried to run the instance (a copy of the whole "./tomcat" directory configered for target machine) of WORKING Openbravo, which was compilled and ran on different computer, but it fails after copying to target computer with mentioned messages. Target computer run under CentOS, working instance was built at **Linux** machine.

Comment: I don't think it is completely compatible with JDK1.7 version. Here is the http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Development_Stack_Setup and also http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/System_Requirements#Server:_Java_based_.3D_multiplatform

Comment: It run with 1.7 JDK on my local machine

Answer (score 1):

Can i know from where you cloned the Openbravo Source Code , Whether you cloned from this url https://code.openbravo.com/erp/devel , Or you downloaded from Openbravo.tar file . If it so please download the latest file and try to install the source .JDK 1.7 is not an issue , Make sure you are using tomcat6.

Comment: Here is a openbravo-3.0MP28.2.tar I am using Tomcat 6. By the way I set up CLASSPATH manually before compiling (ant install.source) to ./lib/runtime , otherwise compilation fails with error